# Correlation tests for circular / symmetrical distributed data

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, cart

This is more of a theoretical exercise, but it may have practical value.

Assuming I have 2 variables, x1 and x2, and a binary outcome that, when plotted, look like in the picture below (red means outcome = 1, blue means outcome = 0).  A decision tree does a great job in predicting the outcome.
What statistical test / method could I use to determine that x1 and x2 are "relevant" to the outcome? I used "relevant" in lack of a better word. Obviously  correlation doesn't work, neither do other types of tests (t-test,  Mann–Whitney). I'd like to use this test / method for feature selection.

[image]

Comment: As a first simple thing to check for, what about comparing variances? (or perhaps the trace if you want a single measure in more than one dimension)... if the variables could be correlated, mean-square Mahalnobis distance might make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, I think you could test whether the sum of the absolute values of the two variables is related to the outcome.  You could do this with a t-test or a logistic regression (if you had other variables to use as well).

Comment: This is an interesting approach and it does work quite nicely. My solution was to calculate the absolute distance from the mean for each variable and then use that in a correlation / t-test, and it produced excellent results.